# jQuery add only one class on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with adding only one class on hover without adding the others. Here is the problem:

HTML:

```
<ul id="ulnav">
    <li><a><img src="images/nav/play.svg" class="animated" id="playnav"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="images/nav/home.svg" class="animated" id="homenav"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="images/nav/mountains.svg" class="animated" id="mountainsnav"/></a></li>
    <li><a><img src="images/nav/contact.svg" class="animated" id="contactnav"/></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a function:

```
var randomAnim = function(){
var result = Math.floor((Math.random()*9) +1);
switch(result) {
    case 1:
        result = "jello";
        break;
    case 2:
        result = "wobble";
        break;
    case 3:
        result = "tada";
        break;
    case 4:
        result = "swing";
        break;
    case 5:
        result = "shake";
        break;
    case 6:
        result = "rubberBand";
        break;
    case 7:
        result = "pulse";
        break;
    case 8:
        result = "bounce";
        break;
    case 9:
        result = "flip";
        break;
}
return result; };
```

and im using it here:

```
   $('#playnav').hover(function() {
     var roll = randomAnim();
     $('#playnav').addClass(roll);
     $(this).on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#playnav').removeClass(roll);
        }, 2000);
     });
 });
```

Its basically adding random animation to #playnav. 
The problem is that if I hover over the playnav element it will add multiple classes - e.g jello, wobble and pulse at the same time, which results in broken animation.

So my question is, how can I add **only one** class on hover?

Comment: Please submit the DOM structure for the problematic part.

Comment: check if the element `hasClass()` any of the possible animation classes and do not add if any are found

Comment: Also, `return ['jello', 'wobble', 'tada', 'swing', 'shake', 'rubberBand', 'pulse', 'bounce', 'flip'][Math.random() * 9 | 0]` is shorter than all this switch

Comment: It looks like you're animating the element, you're hovering over.  The problem may be that when the animation ends, your mouse loses the hover state momentarily, which then forces the re-hover.  To verify, add a counter to see how many times hover is being called.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say that the hover even is being fired multiple times. Instead of `$('#playnav').hover(function(){})` try `$('#playnav').one('hover', function(){})`.  See [jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/one/)

Comment: Change it to mouseenter and mouseleave.  The hover keeps firing and adding more.

Comment: The `$("#playnav").one()` solution is not a good solution if you want the animation to be present also after a new mouseleave; it will never be fired again then. Better to use mouseenter and mouseleave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you want to use `.hover()`  I'd recommend `.mouseenter()`  Single word swap for the fix.

```
$('#playnav').mouseenter(function() {...
```

This will only call your randomization function once, until the cursor leaves and then reenters the element.  In fact, I'd lose the timer too.

```
$('#playnav').mouseenter(function() {
     var roll = randomAnim();
     $('#playnav').addClass(roll);
     $('#playnav').mouseleave(function() {
            $('#playnav').removeClass(roll);
     }); 
});
```

an alternative would be:

```
$('#playnav').mouseenter(function() {
         var roll = randomAnim();
         $('#playnav').addClass(roll);
    });
$('#playnav').mouseleave(function() {
         $('#playnav').attr('class', 'animated');
    });
```

and here is [an updated jsfiddle with CSS library linked in.](https://jsfiddle.net/9jvp8ynp/4/)  Nice effect.  The library link = https://rawgit.com/daneden/animate.css/master/animate.css

And if you wanted to take it one step further, and animate each element independently, you could do this.

```
            $('.animated').mouseenter(function() {
                var roll = randomAnim();
                $(this).addClass(roll);
                $(this).mouseleave(function() {
                    $(this).removeClass(roll);
                });
            });
```

Comment: single word swap for fix doesn't fix. It will happily keep adding classes: https://jsfiddle.net/9jvp8ynp/

Comment: Here's an [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9jvp8ynp/1/) that somebody else started above. It seems to be working fine, even though I don't know which library generates the animations.  No library means no action, but the class names are working fine in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: @yezzz  Funny, I couldn't even see that at your jsfiddle.  There were no images at the links, so that generated errors.  There was no JQuery library, so I added that.  Check link from my comment.  It works as intended.  Not sure what browser you were using.  I'm in Chrome with Dev Tools open.

Comment: I think with my fiddle it will wait for timeout, but it does keep adding classes, even in chrome. Your updated fiddle works fine though.

Comment: Yes, that timeout thing wasn't so good.  I would sure like to know.. what class is creating the animation?  Anybody know?  I'd like to add it to the JS fiddle.

Comment: Apparently its [this class at Github](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css)  Wow, its all CSS, no JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 0):

according to the symptom, hover event gets fired couple of times somehow.
some issues i noticed from the code.

- as  user6188402 mentioned, those switch code can be simplified.

- does not make any sense to put 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd' in the hover event;

- in the event, use $(this) is enough, no need to use the selector again;

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for the responses.
The code Ive used:

```
     $('#playnav').mouseenter(function() {
     var roll = randomAnim();
     $(this).removeClass("jello wobble tada swing shake rubberBand pulse bounce flip").addClass(roll);
     $(this).on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd', function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#playnav').removeClass(roll);
        }, 1500);
     });
 });
```

It looks really good unless you are hovering over the element like crazy(it causes the animation to stop before its even finished).

The animations are from Animate.css (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/);

The class which is causing the animation :

```
.animated { 
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```